# Fortran 77: Specify more than one comment identifier in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, listings

I am trying to specify two types of comment style I have used in my Fortran 77 program (both a `c` and a `!`). At the moment the current program just recognises the `!` and not the `c`. Does anyone know how to get LaTeX to recognise both and colour them (red)?

Here is my LaTeX Code (condensed):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstset{language=[77]fortran,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{purple},
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  morecomment=[s]{!}{c},
  breakatwhitespace=false,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=fortran]
    program main
    implicit integer (A-Z)
c   Asking it to calculate
    x = y+1 !The equation
    end program
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! You appear to be using `listings`. Could you please give us a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) that reproduces the bug? It would make it much easier for us to test.

Comment: Thanks, glad to be here! I have entered the LaTeX code I am playing with (just minus some sections I am using for text).

Comment: Thanks! Been a while since I wrote any Fortran 77 myself.

Comment: This was a little trickier than I thought. But, I think I finally got it.

Comment: Thanks for that, very helpful! I hope this remains useful to one of the three or four people left who still use FORTRAN 77 alongside this specific compiler!

Comment: There are probably more than three or four. Some have it forced upon them by misguided PhD supervisors. Others inflict FORTRAN77 upon themselves.

Comment: @IanThompson Maybe they have to run some really old algorithm that they don’t want to re-write from scratch. Back in the ’90s, Fortran was considered faster than C for HPC, but I can’t say I’ve ever written Fortran-77 by choice.

Comment: It is still used in the civil nuclear industry. Nuclear companies that designed nuclear plants some 20/30/40 years ago (which are still in operation) wouldn't go to the trouble of changing massive reactor simulation programs from 77, the cost is not worth the benefit in many cases. It is still taught on some nuclear-based masters courses.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You aren’t selecting the Fortran-77 dialect in your listing.  According to the language-definition manual, the `c` and `C` comments were removed for Fortran-90 and later, since otherwise `CONTAINS` could start a comment.  The `listing` version of Fortran 77 does not define `!` comments, which I believe your compiler is making available as an extension to Fortran-77.

Therefore, when you select `language=[77]fortran`, you don’t get `!` comments, and when you select `language=fortran`, you don’t get `c` or `C` comments.  However, when you select a language for an individual listing, it reloads that language’s comment rules and overrides your global setting in `\listset`. So, adding the missing definition in the global `\lstset` and removing the unnecessary `language=` from the individual listings works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus} % Or your font of choice
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}

\lstset{language=[77]Fortran,
  showstringspaces=false,
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  stringstyle=\color{purple},
  commentstyle=\color{red},
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  morecomment=[l]!
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
    program main
    implicit integer (A-Z)
c   Asking it to calculate
    x = y+1 !The equation
    end program
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Listing sample]

And so does adding the missing comment style after loading the language.  Note that, within an option, any setting containing brackets must be enclosed in braces.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[77]fortran},
                   morecomment={[l]!}]
```

This is what you should do, removing the `morecomment=` line from `\lstset`, if you’re mixing listings in different languages and `!` should not start a comment in all of them.  If you have to do this a lot, you might define your own environment that wraps this.

You might, in theory, also define your own custom dialect of Fortran listings, for Fortran-77 with Fortran-90 comments.

Answer (score 4):

Your `morecomment` setting is saying that comments begin with `!` and end with `c`. Do this instead.

```
morecomment=[l]{!}
```

`C` is already defined as a comment in the fortran77 style so you shouldn't need to declare it.

All of this is untested.

Comment: This needs to be combined with not specifying the language option to the `lstlisting` environment.